# C++ Segmentation Fault at While Loop

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

For some reason, I'm getting a segmentation fault at this while loop in my code to backtrack a 2d matrix.  I've tried adding numerous conditions to make sure that the matrix will never be accessing an unidentified value.  Here is the code, any help is greatly appreciated!

```
  i = sizeA;
  j = sizeB;

  std::string op[sizeA];

  std::string mat = "match ";
  std::string del = "delete ";
  std::string ins = "insert ";
  std::string sub = "substitute ";

  int k = sizeA;

  bool stop = false;

  while (!stop)
  {
    if ((i == 0) && (j != 0))
    {
      op[k] = (ins + B[j]);
      j = (j - 1);
    }
    else if ((j == 0) && (i != 0))
    {
      op[k] = (del + A[i]);
      i = (i - 1);
    }
    else
    {
      if (smallest(costMatrix[i-1][j], costMatrix[i][j-1], costMatrix[i-1][j-1]) == costMatrix[i-1][j])  //deletion
      {
        op[k] = (del + A[i]);
        i = (i - 1);
      }
      else if (smallest(costMatrix[i-1][j], costMatrix[i][j-1], costMatrix[i-1][j-1]) == costMatrix[i][j-1])  //insertion
      {
        op[k] = (ins + B[j]);
        j = (j - 1);
      }
      else  //substitution or match
      {
        if (costMatrix[i-1][j-1] == costMatrix[i][j])  //match
        {
          op[k] = (mat + A[i]);
        }
        else  //substitution
        {
          op[k] = (sub + B[j]);
        }

        i = (i - 1);
        j = (j - 1);
      }
    }

    if ((i == 0) && (j == 0))
      stop = true;

    k = (k - 1);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign `op[k]` in the first iteration of the loop, you have `k==sizeA`, but `op` is an array of `sizeA`, so this access causes undefined behavior, quite possibly resulting in segmentation fault.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply, that's what it was!